# SQL Server returns unexpected week number

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have some orders in a table and the last order date of 2011 is 20th Dec.

I'm using a sql command to calculate the number of orders in a given week:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATENAME(week,convert(datetime,order_date,103))) AS week, 
  COUNT(1) as orders 
FROM order_table 
where DATENAME(YEAR,convert(datetime,order_date,103)) = '2011' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATENAME(week,convert(datetime,order_date,103))) 
order by week asc
```

It returns me the some of the following results:

```
Week | Orders  
41   | 42  
42   | 110  
43   | 115  
...
...  
51   | 155  
52   | 15
```

The trouble with this is is that the last order date of 2011 as mentioned that I have is 20th Dec 2011, which can't be week 52 so must be week 51.

I've got some other stats(off another system, not SQL server) which giving me some other figures and the last week on it is 51 which I have no doubt is correct. So there's going to be a queries if people are looking both!

Anyone have any idea or know how to sort this?

Thanks,

Comment: Found this interesting for 2012.. http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_many_weeks_in_the_year_2012

Comment: @WilliamDwyer the link is incorrect. Iso_week is determined by the number of thursday of the year. So a week(monday to sunday) where thursday is the second thursday of the year is considered week 2.

Answer (score 10):

The iso_week of 20th Dec 2011 is 51. So maybe that is what you need.

```
SELECT datepart(iso_week, '2011-12-20')
```

Comment: fyi: The calculation for the first iso_week varies by locale (i think standard is week of first thursday) so its possible to have 53 or 54 weeks in a year.

Comment: @Ben: Actually, it's with `WEEK` that you can have 53 or 54 weeks. With `ISO_WEEK` you'll have 52 or 53 (because that would be the number of Thursdays in any given year).

Comment: I agree with Andriiy M. @ben iso_week doesn't vary by anything (that is why it is called iso_week).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Counts a week as Sunday-Saturday, you can use the script below to see how the weeks break out for 2011.  The 1st of January is a Saturday, which means the first week is only 1 day.  There are 53 SQL weeks in 2011, and 53 weeks in most years

```
DECLARE @dStartDate DATETIME

SET @dStartDate = '01/01/2011'

WHILE @dStartDate < '01/01/2012'
BEGIN

PRINT   CONVERT(VARCHAR, @dStartDate, 101) 
        + ' : ' 
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(WEEK, @dStartDate)) 
        + ' : ' 
        + DATENAME(DW, @dStartDate)

SET @dStartDate = @dStartDate + 1

END
```

If you want to change the day SQL counts as the first of the week, you can use the DATEFIRST command

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DatePart(WEEK,order_date) AS WeekOfYear
FROM order_table
```

Should give you the week number.

Comment: I think you have some VB syntax in there. Should be spelled out `WEEK` with no double quotes, not `"ww"`. (Yes I know SQL Server accepts ww but why not spell it out so it's clear whether it's weekday, weeknumber, etc.? `w`, `wk` and `ww` are all supported shorthand, can you recite them? I can't. See https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx ...)

Comment: Always following me about aren't you @AaronBertrand - Thanks for the advice - I'll edit it. :-)

Comment: Don't think I'm picking on you or following you specifically. I'm trying to prevent a lot of people from perpetuating poor coding practices.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I didn't mean it to sound like that - I appreciate the advice. I'd just posted an answer using DATEADD on another thread - I've edited that thread to match the good practices you've pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

So do

```
Select * from order_table Where DatePart(Week, order_date) = 52
```

See what is week 52 not what you think is 52.

PS Given you are starting week 1 on the 1/1 it's not possible to have a 52 week year, unless 1 and or 52 are not seven day weeks.