# SQL Server - select rows that fall in this week

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(INTERVIEW_ID) 
FROM Interviews AS i INNER JOIN CVsSent AS cvt ON i.CVSENT_ID = cvt.CVSENT_ID  
WHERE cvt.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID 
AND (i.DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
AND i.DATE_TIME < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 1)))
AS INTERVIEW_COUNT_DAY
```

which selects a count for today. I need a query which selects a count for this week, starting from Sunday (day 1) finishing Saturday (day 7), as opposed to the last 7 days. Is this possible?

Comment: You could try comparing the `week` and `year` DATEPARTs of the current day and the date stored in your table? More information on DATEPART [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174420.aspx).

Comment: Similarish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620970/week-numbers-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @FirstDayOfWeek DATETIME
    , @LastDayOfWeek DATETIME

SELECT 
      @FirstDayOfWeek = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6)
    , @LastDayOfWeek = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, GETDATE()), 5)

SELECT 
      INTERVIEW_COUNT_DAY = COUNT(INTERVIEW_ID)
    , DATEPART(weekday, DATE_TIME)
FROM dbo.Interviews i 
JOIN dbo.CVsSent cvt ON i.CVSENT_ID = cvt.CVSENT_ID  
WHERE cvt.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID 
    AND (i.DATE_TIME >= @FirstDayOfWeek AND i.DATE_TIME < @LastDayOfWeek)
GROUP BY DATEPART(weekday, DATE_TIME)
```

**UPDATED:**

```
DECLARE @PrevWeek DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())

DECLARE
      @FirstDayOfPrevWeek DATETIME = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, @PrevWeek), 6)
    , @LastDayOfPrevWeek DATETIME = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, @PrevWeek), 5)

SELECT @FirstDayOfPrevWeek, @LastDayOfPrevWeek
```

Comment: Won't that just restrict to records in the current day?

Comment: @Devart thanks very much, your answer worked appropriately. how can I extend this to get all rows from last week?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
For week 1st day "sunday" use:

```
DATEADD(Week, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000101', '29-Apr-2013'), '19000101') - 1
```

and for week last day "saturday"use:

```
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000101', '29-Apr-2013') + 1, '19000101') - 2
```

Comment: I have used 29-Apr-2013 you can use GetDate() for current week or as required.